# Replacing a string in SQL using STUFF with a string that is smaller than the string to replace

Tags: sql-server, string

I need to replace a string in SQL in the middle of a url that is the folder path with another folder path.  The folder path to replace will be smaller, larger or the same size as the one that is being replaced. I am trying to use `STUFF` but it only replaces the same number of characters that I am inserting.

How can I accommodate varies string lengths to replace?
This is my SQL 
In the example below I want to replace **UDS+Reports%2fDSParameterizedDynamicReports** with **UDSReports%2fPWReports**

```
DECLARE @StartPosition int, @StringLength int
DECLARE @NewFilePath varchar(max) = 'http://servername/ReportServer?%2fUDS+Reports%2fDSParameterizedDynamicReports%2fPatientsbyCode'
DECLARE @ReportFilePath varchar(200) = 'UDSReports/PWReports'
SELECT @ReportFilePath = REPLACE(REPLACE(@ReportFilePath, ' ', '+'), '/', '%2f')
SELECT @ReportFilePath
DECLARE @StartPosition int, @StringLength int, @ParameterList varchar(max)
SELECT @StartPosition = CHARINDEX('%2f', @NewFilePath) + 1 
SELECT  @StartPosition
        SELECT @StringLength = REVERSE(CHARINDEX('%2f', @NewFilePath)) - @StartPosition 
SELECT @StringLength
        SELECT @NewFilePath = STUFF(@NewFilePath, @StartPosition, @StringLength, @ReportFilePath)
SELECT @NewFilePath
```

Comment: please write out the desired final select output

Comment: @GloriaSantin Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your original attempt is that `REVERSE(CHARINDEX('%2f', @NewFilePath))` should have been `CHARINDEX('f2%', reverse(@NewFilePath))`

Once you are looking for a pattern in the reverse of a string, you also need to reverse the pattern, so `'%2f'` becomes `'f2%'`.

Another issue is that `charindex()` returns the start position of the pattern, so with a 3 length pattern, you need to adjust the output accordingly.

Here are two corrected versions, one using stuff and one without stuff:

without `stuff()`: concatenating the beginning and end of the first string around the new middle

```
set @newfilepath = 
  left(@newfilepath,charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+2)
  +@reportfilepath
  +right(@newfilepath,charindex('f2%',reverse(@newfilepath))+2)
```

with `stuff()`:

```
set @newfilepath = stuff(
    @newfilepath
  , (charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+3)
  , len(@newfilepath)
    -(charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+2)
    -(charindex('f2%',reverse(@newfilepath))+2)
  , @reportfilepath 
  )
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/GDFFV41538

```
declare @startposition int, @stringlength int, @parameterlist varchar(max)

declare @newfilepath varchar(max) = 'http://servername/ReportServer?%2fUDS+Reports%2fDSParameterizedDynamicReports%2fPatientsbyCode'
declare @reportfilepath varchar(200) = 'UDSReports/PWReports'
select @reportfilepath = replace(replace(@reportfilepath, ' ', '+'), '/', '%2f')

;with cte as (
select  
    LeftPart=left(@newfilepath,charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+2)
  , MiddlePart=@reportfilepath
  , RightPart=right(@newfilepath,charindex('f2%',reverse(@newfilepath))+2)
  , woStuff=
      left(@newfilepath,charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+2)
      +@reportfilepath
      +right(@newfilepath,charindex('f2%',reverse(@newfilepath))+2)   
  , wStuff = stuff(
        @newfilepath
      , (charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+3)
      , len(@newfilepath)
          -(charindex('%2f',@newfilepath)+2)
          -(charindex('f2%',reverse(@newfilepath))+2)
      ,@reportfilepath 
      )

)
select 
    wostuff =replace(wostuff,'%2f','/')
  , wstuff  =replace(wstuff,'%2f','/')
  , samesame=case when wStuff=woStuff then 'true' else 'false' end
from cte
```